# Groupby Cumulative with reset when Cumulative become negative

Tags: pandas, numpy, reset, cumsum

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
   Category  Value
0         A      7
1         A      6
2         A      8
3         A     -9
4         A    -20
5         A      5
6         A      6
7         B      8
8         B      9
9         B    -20
10        B     -5
11        B    -30
12        B      5
```

I would like to cumulative column "Value" by "Category" group, however, the cumulative would be reset when cumulated value is less than zero. My expected result in column "Cummulative":

```
   Category  Value  Cumulative
0         A      7           7
1         A      6          13
2         A      8          21
3         A     -9          12
4         A    -20           0
5         A      5           5
6         A      6          11
7         B      8           8
8         B      9          17
9         B    -20           0
10        B     -5           0
11        B    -30           0
12        B      5           5
```

With the result in "Cummulative", I need to add a "Result, which if "Cummulative" is zero, it will take the negative of "Cummulative" from previous row else take the "Value", expected result:

[image]

How to code in phyton?

Expected result

[image]

Comment: Please take the time to read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question accordingly

Answer (score 1):

This is not easily vectorizable, you need to loop:

```
def cumsum_reset(s):
    S = 0
    out = []
    for x in s:
        S += x
        S = max(0, S)
        out.append(S)
    return out

df['Cumulative'] = df.groupby('Category')['Value'].transform(cumsum_reset)
```

Output:

```
   Category  Value  Cumulative
0         A      7           7
1         A      6          13
2         A      8          21
3         A     -9          12
4         A    -20           0
5         A      5           5
6         A      6          11
7         B      8           8
8         B      9          17
9         B    -20           0
10        B     -5           0
11        B    -30           0
12        B      5           5
```